# how to expose property on component in vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js

I am thinking how to implement validation on vue.js component.

The initial idea is that component validates and return an error code, like: "require", "min", "max" etc. Another component will display full text message according to this error code.

Because error message might not always display inside component's template. I need two separated components.

pseudo code is like this.

```
<div>
<mycomponent ref="salary" errcode="ErrorCode"></mycomponent>
</div>
.....
<div>
<errormessage watchcomponent="salary" message="salaryErrorMessages"></errormessage>
</div>
```

salaryErrorMessages is a hash of codes and messages. for example:
{"require":"please enter salary",
"min": "minimum salary value is 10000"}

Vue has ref attribute on component, . I don't know if I can use ref to reference a component in attribute.

Other solutions I considered:

1. add an error object in model of the page, and pass into  using :sync binding.  can monitor same object.
   This requires to declare error messages in model.

If I consider the requirement that page also needs to know if there is an error before post back. a global error object might be necessary.

2. use event bus or Vuex. 
   This seems official solution, but I don't know .

When a page has multiple instances of , they will trigger same event. all  instances will monitor same event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working literally backwards. Vue is about passing data from parent to child, not exposing child properties to parent components.

> add an error object in model of the page, and pass into using :sync binding. can monitor same object. This requires to declare error messages in model.

`sync` is gone from Vue v2, but the idea is fundamentally sort of correct: a parent component holds one object, child components get passed chunks of it as props, parent object automagically gets updated in the parent when it is changed in a child. It doesn't have to be the root component.

> use event bus or Vuex. This seems official solution, but I don't know .

Vuex is pretty much always the Correct solution if you have an application that needs to manage a lot of state-related shenanigans.

> When a page has multiple instances of , they will trigger same event. all instances will monitor same event.

Vue will very frequently pollute your console with warnings that [`data` must be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function). This is why!

Here is an abridged version really shameful hackjob I <s>inflicted on innocen</s> made for an acquaintance recently:

In my defense, putting things in `__proto__` is a very quick way to make them non-enumerable.

```js
Vue.component('error', {
  template: '#error',
  props: ['condition', 'errorMessage']
})

Vue.component('comp', {
  template: '#comp',
  props: ['errorMessage', 'model'],
})

Vue.component('app', {
  template: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      models: {
        nameForm: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          __proto__: {
            validator: function(value) {
              return _(value).every(x => x.length > 2)
            }
          }
        },
        otherForm: {
          notVeryInterestingField: 'There are words here',
          veryImportantField: 0,
          __proto__: {
            validator: function(value) {
              return value.veryImportantField > 20
            }
          }
        },
        __proto__: {
          validator: function(value) {
            return _(value).every(x => x.validator(x))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root'
})
```

```css
.error {
  background: orange
}
.alright {
  background: mediumaquamarine
}
 section > div, pre {
  padding: 6px;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
}
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.6/dist/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>

<template id="comp">
  <div :class="[model.validator(model) ? 'alright' : 'error']" style="display: flex; border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4)">
    <section>
      <div v-for="(field, fieldName) in model">
        {{_.startCase(fieldName)}}:
        <input v-model="model[fieldName]">
        <br>
      </div>
      <error :condition="!model.validator(model)" :error-message="errorMessage"></error>
    </section>
    <section>
      <pre>props: {{$options.propsData}}</pre>
    </section>
  </div>

</template>

<template id="error">
  <div v-if="condition">
    {{ errorMessage || 'Oh no! An error!' }}
  </div>
</template>

<template id="app">
  <div :class="[models.validator(models) ? 'alright' : 'error']">
    <comp :model="model" error-message="Mistakes were made." v-for="model in models"></comp>
    <pre>data: {{$data}}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="root">
  <app></app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. i will have to use Vuex because my page does not have a parent component. Its structure is a page with many components inside.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use Vuex. Not only it solves your problem, but it gives you huge scalability in your project.